# Send a mail after the due date is over in project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, pwa

I have created one project in project server and uploaded in my site.The Project date is over.But  i don't know the project is completed or not.so i have to send mail to resouce person as YOUR PROJECT DATE IS OVER.How can i send like this?Any possible way is there using pwa settings in my site?
I am using sharepoint 2016 onpremise.

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended that you could use workflow to get the achievement, just two actions:
1.when an item is created run the workflow automatically, then wait until the Due Date

2.send the mail

[image]